# Finding the condition for point of intersection of three normals to a given parabola

Tags: conic-sections, cubics

**Question:**
Suppose that the normals at three different points on the parabola $y^2=4x$ pass through the point (h,0). Show that h>2.

---

**My attempt:**

Equation of normal to parabola $y^2=4x$:

$$y=mx-2am-mx^3$$
$$a=1$$
the normals also pass through point $(h,0)$
$$0=mh-2m-m^3$$ 
$$m^3+2m-mh=0$$ 
Since three lines are passing through a single point and as parallel lines do not intersect, the three lines need to have three different slopes. So there must be three real and distinct values of m.

$$\Delta > 0$$
$$18abcd-4b^3d+b^2c^2-4ac^3-27a^2d^2>0$$
$$-4ac^3-27a^2d^2>0$$
$$4h^3>27(2)^2$$
$$h>3$$
I am getting a different condition for the intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to delve into cubic equations, because your equation can be reduced very easily by taking out $m$:
$$m(m^2+2-h)=0$$

So we have either $m=0$ or $m=\pm\sqrt{h-2}$ and therefore $h\ge2$